# Array in loop and show data by groups

Tags: php, loops

I try show data in loop by groups , actually i have array with many elements and need show in group of 4 , 5 , etc

I put example :

```
$array_values=array(
  "2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3",
  "5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5"
);

$c=0;
foreah($array_values as $array_value) {
  print $array_value

  if($c%3) {
    print "<br><br>";
  }
  $c++;   
}
```

As you can see in example, in this case I want put "<br>" , each 3 elements in loop and in other cases can be each 4 or more elements , I try this but no get good results , in some cases show well in other cases all bad

I don´t know  how can i do this , thank´s for the help

Comment: You must increment $c `$c++;` And make the comparison right. `if($c%3 == 0)`

Comment: I use that also and no works in some cases show 3 and in other cases show 5 elements , no cut right

Comment: You want it to show 235, 235, 235 ... each on it's own line?

Comment: Yes but in other cases can be other number , yes right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all solutions, there's more than one way to do it.

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to grab values 3 at a time from the array.

```
for ($c = 0; $c < count($array_values); $c+=3)     {
    print(implode(array_slice($array_values, $c, 3)));
    print "<br><br>";
}
```

You also can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to break up the array into 3-bite segments:

```
foreach (array_chunk($array_values, 3) as $row) {
    print(implode($row));
    print "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the remainder of `$c%3` is 0. But if you want it to be another length in another case you'll have to add that in. But this should get you started.

```
$array_values=array("2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5","2","3","5");

$c=1;
foreach($array_values as $array_value)
{
    print $array_value;

    if($c%3 === 0)
    {
        print "<br><br>";
    }
    $c++;   
}
```

Running that gives me this output:

```
235

235

235

235

235

235

235

235

235

235
```